# How can I transfer data from one form to another in a windows forms application?

Tags: c#

Im creating a windows forms application using C#.

I have an integer and it contains a value that needs to be printed in the form next in the application. How can I have it available for use in the second form ?

Answer (score 0):

There are so many methods to pass data between forms in Windows application:

- Using constructor
- Using objects
- Using properties
- Using delegates

Try to this link:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14122/Passing-Data-Between-Forms

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Constructor that allows you to pass it in while still calling the parameterless constructor that probably initializes the controls for the form in some *.designer.cs.

```
// example

private int m_passedInValue;

public MyForm2()
{
  InitializeConstrols();
}

public MyForm2(int thePassedValue)
 : this()
{
  m_passedInValue = thePassedValue;
}

// the form1 call
void SomeOpenFormMethod()
{
  var form2 = new MyForm2(20);
  form2.Show();
}
```